# .Net How to create a custom ThreadPool shared across all the AppDomain of a process?

Tags: .net, appdomain, threadpool

I made a custom ThreadPool optimized for my specific needs. However, when there are multiple AppDomains in the process, the CLR ThreadPool is able to be shared across all the AppDomains and I would like to be able to reproduce this behavior.

This could be done using MarshalByRefObject and Remoting in order to create a distributed ThreadPool, but I fear that it will add unwanted overhead since the key goal of the custom thread pool is performance.

Another theoretical solution would be to hack the AppDomain memory boundary using an unmanaged object. If I'm correct, the memory boundary in AppDomain only apply to managed objects, so there could be one managed wrapper in each AppDomain all pointing to the same unmanaged object.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make a custom
   thread pool using remoting with
   minimal overhead?
2. If not, is it
   possible to share an unmanaged
   object across AppDomain?

Comment: What prompted the decision to write a custom threadpool?  What functionality was missing from the .NET threadpool?

Comment: The CLR ThreadPool can't prioritize work items queued into the pool. The CCR Dispatcher offer some great possibilities and I think that an hybrid between the CCR Dispatcher and the CLR ThreadPool would be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking more about it, it's probably a bad idea to try to reimplement a process wide ThreadPool, the CLR ThreadPool is already optimized for this.

For my case, I wanted more flexibility to be able to prioritize work items queued into the pool, this can be done with a layer built on top of the existing CLR ThreadPool.

Comment: That sounds practical. I wonder how you do this while avoiding context switching too much. I also need a cross-appdomain thread pool but performance is key.

Comment: The CLR ThreadPool is already cross-appdomain. If you want to make a custom one, I think the "easiest" way is to do it in managed c++. But since .Net 4, the CLR ThreadPool is well optimized and it would be hard to do better. The weakness I see with the CLR ThreadPool is that it is not well isolated, any piece of code in the process that slightly block a threadpool's thread will screw any real-time performance. It would be great if we could create an isolated instance of the CLR ThreadPool.

Comment: It seems that there is a Coop Fiber example in the .Net 2.0 SDK that shows how to do exactly what you decide and it allows intercepting all calls to the O/S and any syncrhonization objects that might get blocked so you can switch to a different Fiber.

Comment: Scratch my last comment. It appears they removed. Plus, Duh! I'm using 3.5 of the SDK...2.0 is too old to play with now.  3.5 and 4.0 don't support, it seems User Mode Scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new threadpool instance in each appdomain, but then use a [semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to control the total number of threads running across all instances. This means you can still get the same total concurrent jobs processed, but don't have the grief of marshalling.

The MSDN docs have an example.

Comment: A thread pool is optimal when is has one thread per cpu. With your solution, threads are not shared across appdomain. So if you have five AppDomain queuing work items and have only 4 cpu core, you need 5 threads to be able to execute all the work items, this is not optimal.

Comment: Optimal for what? If your threads may be IO-bound, then one-thread-per-cpu is extremely suboptimal. The framework's threadpool originally maxed out at 25/cpu, and is now 250/cpu; never 1/cpu. A semaphore using Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads() would simulate the framework's current operation.

With remoting, there's always going to be the marshalling overhead, so each thread is going to have a higher startup cost than you'd probably prefer. As to sharing an unmanaged object; sounds to me like you're opening yourself a world of pain and bugs. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: You are right that I should have stated optimal for cpu bound processing. However, even for IO bound processing, blocking a threadpool thread with a IO operation is rarely a good idea, it should use IO completion port instead.